# What is a collective term for animals that people can ride?

Tags: word-request

Such animals as donkeys, camels and horses. I'm sure this word exists in English. I knew it for some time, but it has slipped my mind recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mount](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mount)

> *An animal, usually a horse, used to ride on, unlike a draught horse*

Comment: Exactly! That's the one. I'll make sure it stays in mind this time. Thank you :)

Comment: I also see mount can be used as verb. I am wondering which one is correct, mount a motorcycle vs mount on a motorcycle?

Comment: "The rider **mounted** his horse." versus "The rider **mounted on** his horse."?